# Checkbox to agree before login

Tags: html

It's my first time using HTML and would like to incorporate a checkbox that will enable or disable the "login" button if the user doesn't tick the checkbox to agree and enable the button when the box is tick.

```html
<td>
  <input style="width: 80px" name="username" type="text" value="$(username)" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right" class="style6">Password</td>
  <td>
    <input style="width: 80px" name="password" type="password" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>


<div class="notice" style="color: #c1c1c1; font-size: 12px">
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="check" id="agree" />I agree to the statement above.
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: You will need javascript to enable/disable a button based on the checkbox being checked/unchecked.  If you follow Quentin's answer then the form cannot be submitted unless the required checkbox is checked.

Comment: Here is a possible solution with raw Javascript https://jsfiddle.net/bqn0rz0k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add [the `required` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute).

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the help!

Comment: I encountered a permission error while using the "required" attribute. Can someone point me to the right attribute when using xhtml?

[IMG]http://i64.tinypic.com/30wntrk.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: @David — Give the value explicitly. `required="required"`. Better yet, stop using XHTML. It is more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: I'm trying to understand that now. xhtml is really a pain in the. But I guess I have to work with this for now before I can move on from it.

I've done what you suggested but I can't seem to make it work.

http://s12.postimg.org/uj3soe3n1/test.png

Comment: @David — You'll need to use XHTML 5. They didn't have the required attribute when XHTML 1 was published last century.

Comment: I see. So there's no way doing this in XHTML 1? No work around?

Comment: If you want to do it XHTML 1 then you have to use JavaScript. There's no good reason to use XHTML 1 now (X)HTML 5 is a standard.

Comment: I have tried the javascript by Daryon Gallardo (link above) but can't get pass the 'disable' attribute. I'm still learning the basics and it's already causing me headache. 

http://s18.postimg.org/dj4u73i5l/test1.png

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a bit of javascript like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="check" id="agree" onclick="if(this.checked){ document.getElementById('login').disabled=true; }else{ document.getElementById('login').disabled=false; }" />
```

You just have to give an ID to your submit button !

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it with javascript you can try this ( Use @Quention Solution in my opinion it's better )

```js
document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;

function agree() {
  if (document.getElementById('agree').checked) {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
  <td><input style="width: 80px" name="username" type="text" value="$(username)" required/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" class="style6">Password</td>
    <td><input style="width: 80px" name="password" type="password"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>

    <td><input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>


  <div class="notice" style="color: #c1c1c1; font-size: 12px"><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="check" id="agree" onclick="agree()"  required/> I agree to the statement above.
    <br q v/>
  </div>
```

Comment: I encountered a permission error while using the "required" attribute. Can someone point me to the right attribute when using xhtml?

http://i64.tinypic.com/30wntrk.jpg